# What is value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Error_Code) 
       FROM 
           (SELECT Connection_type, Error_Code, Count 
            FROM
                (SELECT 
                     Connection_Type, error_code, count(*) AS count,
                     row_number() over(partition by Connection_Type order by count(*) desc) as ROWNUM 
                 FROM
                     Staging 
                 WHERE
                     TransactionDate >= convert(varchar, getdate() -1, 111) 
                     AND Status != 'Deliver'
                 GROUP BY
                     Connection_Type, error_code) a 
            WHERE
                rownum <= 10) c
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
```

What does the line

```
.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'
```

mean?

Comment: Your sql query is converted to xml. To get control over it, you have used `FOR XML PATH('')` and value performs a XQuery on the xml that finally returns the required output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *value* method converts the XML data to NVARCHAR, because the *STUFF* function (it removes the first comma from the list of values) expect character expression as first argument.

You can try this here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc078/23)

If you remove the *value*, you got an error.

Comment: thanks for writing and second thing what is use of that TYPE ?

Comment: Tells the query to returns as XML, so actually if you take it out, you don't need the _VALUE_ either.